# Where to find didactic video stories in simple German

Tags: resource-request, german

I have troubles to find some bigger resource of German video stories for language begginers. All the resources on Youtube I found are:

- without video record (just plain talking with subtitles),
- or way too advanced (regular movies, tv series etc.)
- or way too much for children (and short in lenght) - for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ7Vsi4W3BE&list=PL5D443A49838608D1&index=1

So what I am looking for is:

- interesting for adults (best would be documentary, but not necessarilly)
- with video "background" helping to understand what is the topic
- long enough - the best would be something like large number of 30 minutes vidoes

Notes:

- ultimately the best would be some kind of course, where the stories are ordered and building up the languge difficulty
- maybe I am missing something not obvious, but good enough - for example some German tv news for "simple people" with english subtitles
- the best what I have found so far is the SouthPark in german (that is accessible from Germany online), but it is still little bit too complicated (althought the contex is pretty obvious most of the times)

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: On many YouTube videos you can turn on auto-generated subtitles, and then turn on auto-translate to your preferred language. That's two layers of AI between you and what's actually being said, so getting even the gist of the conversion from that is a challenge, but if you're doing it for language practice I suppose that's all the better.

Answer (score 4):

I have some recommendations for you.

1. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbxb2fqe9oNgglAoYqsYOtQ/featured) you can find videos about everyday life in Germany. I think, this is a quite nice channel, representing German by authentic language examples. The playlists are sorted by levels and always with German and English subtitles.
2. [This link](https://www.ndr.de/fernsehen/service/leichte_sprache/Alle-Nachrichten-in-Leichter-Sprache,leichtesprachearchiv118.html) leads to news in simple language from Northern German Broadcasting, which can as well be found [here](https://www.mdr.de/nachrichten-leicht/index.html) for Central German Broadcasting and [here](https://www.sr.de/sr/home/nachrichten/nachrichten_einfach/index.html) for Saarland.
3. [This movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-eDoThe6qo) is for beginners and uses only basic German. The story is not that catchy though...
4. [This](https://www.youtube.com/user/KurzgesagtDE) is a channel with small documentaries (each 10 min). You can add subtitles if you like, because they are not that easy to understand.
5. You said you didn't like children's stuff - but [Piggeldy und Frederick](https://www.youtube.com/user/piggeldy) are just great. Even for adults it might be interesting how words we use every day (like wind (Wind) or silence (Stille) are explained here.
6. As I don't know which level you have (exactly), it is a bit hard to find more long videos/movies/documentaries. Most of them use quite advanced vocabulary. But you can find many of them in German Broadcasting Services like ARD, ZDF & Co. [Arte](https://www.arte.tv/de/videos/wissenschaft/) might be a good fit, it exists in German, English, French, Polish, Spanish and Italian. You can watch documentaries with subtitles there.

You can give me a feedback in the comments if this is what you have been looking for and if it meets your taste and language level. If not, maybe I can give more examples.